# Существует ли форма "двигаемый"?

Tags: причастия

Существует ли форма "двигаемый" (от глагола двигать (движет))? Является ли она литературным / нейтральным вариантом? или разговорным?

Comment: От глагола "двигает".  А от "движет" — "движимый".

Answer (score 0):

Есть слова двигаемый и движимый от передвигаться(глагол) и движение(образ действия). Можно передвигаться на ногах, осуществляя и при необходимости контролируя передвижение нижних конечностей(ерунда получилась).

Двигаемый - это про механическое движение, когда что-то двигается под действием внешней физической силы - передвигается, перемещается, движение формы без внутреннего изменения:

> Сто невольников, пригвожденных ко скамьям корабля, веслами двигаемого в пути своем, живут в тишине и устройстве; но загляни в их сердце и душу. Радищев.

> А между тем он все бежал да бежал, и словно двигаемый какою-то постороннею силою, ибо во всем существе своем чувствовал какое-то ослабление и онемение; думать ни о чем он не мог, хотя идеи его цеплялись за все, как терновник. Достоевский.

Движимый - это про душевные движение, подвижность души, чувства, одушевление, изменение, оживление:

> Движимый состраданием, он швырнул ему один хлеб, на который тот бросился, подобно бешеной собаке, изгрыз, искусал его и тут же, на улице, в страшных судорогах испустил дух от долгой отвычки принимать пищу. Гоголь.

> Она с трудом раскрыла глаза. Большое колесо, движимое водою, шумя, вертелось перед нею, и далеко летели вокруг него брызги. Отражая луну, они напомнили ей алмазы, которыми девушки украшали ее в саду в тот день, когда приехал Серебряный. Толстой.

> Некоторые догадывались об истине и утверждали, что виновником сего ужасного бедствия был сам Дубровский, движимый злобой и отчаянием. Пушкин.

Из нового:

> Он промолчал. Затем послышался звук двигаемого стула, и всё стихло. Анна Дубчак.

А вот это уже звучит специфично, хотя даёт ощущение, что "люди" это биологические механизмы, двигаемые инстинктами, то есть какие-то не правильные люди, очевидно:

> Оно могло бы попасть в руки людей с сильным умом, но недисциплинированными желаниями, людей, двигаемых эгоистическими инстинктами, ищущих пользы только для себя и не интересующихся общим благом.Анни Безант.

Answer (score 0):

Есть глагол ‟двигать” (например, двигать стол), от этого глагола можно образовать активное и страдательное причастие – двигающий и двигаемый. Так что да, есть такая форма, как ‟двигаемый”. Слово ‟движимый” – это другое слово, которое обозначает воздействие мотивов, чувств, размышлений, – например: ‟Движимый злобой, он совершал много ошибок”.